# How to pass user-configurable parameters to AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs

Suppose that I have an AngularJS application that communicates with some external HTTP API and show the results to user.

As far as I know, it's a great idea to move API-related code to the service like `APIService`.

But suppose that user can specify IP address and port of this API via GUI controls. What should I do in this case? Pass additional `ip` and `port` parameters on each service method call?

```
app.service('APIService', function() {
  this.getUsers = function(ip, port) {
    return /* ... */;
  };

  this.createuser = function(ip, port, name, email) {
    return /* ... */
  };
});
```

Or should I somehow store them inside service object?

Comment: You could create a factory that will create you an object that represents your service with the provided init data (ip, port). However you would have to discard, in some or other form, that object should the user change that data. The other option of passing them into every function may look uglier but would mean you need a service not a factory and don't need to worry about creating and discarding objects.

Comment: I think that configuration is something that has to be stored in this case, isn't it? Is this part of the app? or this is something like an authentication phase?